# How to prevent firefox window manual resizing?

Tags: javascript, firefox, windows-7

I use the last firefox release (45.02) on windows 7.

I want to prevent user to resize manually the windows. I have a non responsive GUI, and I want to fix the browser interface.

I can't use the javascript resizeTo(...) function  because of [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.resizeTo)

Comment: The fix here is to put time and effort into the GUI to make it responsive, not spending time and effort trying to force your users to use the size of window you want.

Comment: I'm agree with you in most of cases. But in my case, this window is a part of a larger interface in different techs (not only web pages).

This is not a web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reasonably do this. Which is a Good Thing. The *user* is in control of their browser, not you.

You *can* control the size of a popup (including whether it can be resized), within reason, so temporarily while you sort out the responsive thing, you could provide users a link to open a window in the size you want:

```
<a href="#" id="open-window">Open window in XxY for best experience of this site.</a>
```

then

```
document.getElementById("open-window").addEventListener("click", function() {
    window.open("http://example.com", "", "width=640,height=480,resizable=no");
}, false);
```

Note that some browsers may still allow resizing, either in the normal way or via a small "grippy" (as the Firefox folks call it).